# Want to keep Notes only on my iPhone 6

Tags: iphone

I want to keep my Notes only on my iPhone 6 and not have them appear in my mail account but I have been unable to disable notes without deleting them from my iPhone. I tried to find the On My iPhone option in Notes settings to set the default account but it is not there, nor is it available in Mail, Contacts, and Calendar settings. Please advise.

Comment: Are you asking about syncing with iCloud or a computer? Both you can specify notes not to be sync'd.

Answer (score 1):

If the notes are associated with your email account you'll have to copy them somewhere (you can email them, send them as text, iMessage,  copy and paste them but only one by one), delete them —which will happen automatically when you disable them on Settings > Mail, contacts, calendars— and then add them back to reside exclusively on your iPhone.
Consider making regular backups of your device, because if anything happens to it, that will be your only way of recovering them.